# Puzzle about subjects, classroom numbers and teachers who teach those subjects in classrooms

Tags: puzzle

A,B,C,D,E are teachers who may teach: math, physics, chemistry, biology or geography(one subject per person, we don't know who teaches what).

They teach in classrooms 110,111,112,113,114. **Tell which teacher teaches which subject in which classroom**

1. D teaches in classroom which's number is bigger or smaller by 2  than number of classroom that E teaches in.
2. A teaches in classroom which's number is smaller by 1 than number of classroom, that B teahes in.
3. C teaches maths or physics.
4. A  does not teaches chemistry. Chemistry is not taught in 110 or 112.
5. Bilogy is not taught by A nor E.
6. In classroom 113 there is no physics or geography.
7. B teaches in classroom which's number is bigger than C's,D's and E's classroom.

The problem is that I don't know how to draw a table for that puzzle. Should it be 3 dimensional, or 3 2d arrays?

Comment: Three 2D arrays is an orthographic projection of a 3D array. If this doesn't lose information (e.g. there are no clues that eliminate a single point as opposed to an entire line in 3-space), then the 2D arrays are much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three things which you want to put together.

```
- Teacher letter
- Subject
- Classroom
```

So the table could look like this:

[image: Table]

There seem to be two solutions though :/
[image: Solved]

Answer (score 2):

Multiple $2\mathrm{d}$ arrays would be optimal. Note the answer by user $Alex$ uses the traditional 'logic table'.

In most cases, solving problems like this you will display all of the variables in pairs. For example(If you don't understand this example please let me know).

When graphing a region for integration, you can break the problem up into $(x,y)$,$(x,z)$ and $(y,z)$ to get a full idea of the relationship between each of the variables.

Note: This problem is not uniquely solvable, criteria $2-7$ can be met, and criteria $1$ can be solved in two ways without breaking $2-7$.